# How to set the status and send a body with Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have the following case. The user need to be able to upload a spreadsheet (csv) but if there are errors (for example a value supposed to be a Integer is not a number) I need to display the full csv as a table with a red background on the invalid cell. I would like to set the status to 422, but I haven't find a way to do so. All the ways I found to set a status seems to "fail" the handler Monad and doesn't allow to specify a message body. I was expecting a setStatus or equivalent but I can't find it. Is there a way to do it, or is it against Http protocol do to so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for

[`sendResponseStatus :: (MonadHandler m, ToTypedContent c) => Status -> c -> m a`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.14/yesod-core-1.4.20.2/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:sendResponseStatus).

Comment: It works indeed. I just struggled a bit to mix with my do block. I add to do `sendResponseStatus status >>= defaultLayout body` and it works. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to do so without throwing an exception?